# Not able to use plugins with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack 4.7.0 with webpack-cli installed. This is for a react-js app. Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  'inject': 'body'
});


module.exports = {
  entry: './client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

Now when I run the command node_modules.bin\webpack --config webpack.config.js, I get the following error message:

> plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
>     ^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

And I am not able to build my application. Here is my `npm -v & node -v`: `5.7.1
v9.4.0`. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Also: it shows a very long error with the files being related to `require`-ing.

Comment: Webpack 4.7.0 doesn't exist. Latest version is 4.1.1.

Comment: If you are using webpack 4.x, make sure you have installed the correct `html-webpack-plugin`. I needed to install `webpack-contrib/html-webpack-plugin` instead of the regular version for it to work with webpack 4.x.

Comment: is it possible that the omission of the comma (before the `plugins` key) triggers this ?

Comment: @MaieonBrix this

Comment: @MaieonBrix Thanks! I am following a tutorial so did not notice any stuff in the code

Comment: Haha no worry, keep coding :)